# fastapi post method call with and without trailing slashes

Tags: python-3.x, fastapi, starlette

I was trying to write a fastapi post method as:

```
@app.post('/method/final_path/', tags=['method/final_path'])
```

When i do a postman call as
**https://......./method/final_path/**
I get the expected result, but if the call is changed to  **https://......./method/final_path**
I get 405-method not allowed.

According to FastAPI docs, the trailing slashes shouldn't matter, so ideally

```
@app.post('/method/final_path/', tags=['method/final_path'])
@app.post('/method/final_path', tags=['method/final_path'])
```

with postman calls:

- **https://......./method/final_path/**
- **https://......./method/final_path**

all the above 4 combinations should give the same result. Then what am I doing wrong?

Versions:
fastapi-0.63
starlette-0.13.6

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried defining it just without the trailing slash, instead of with it?

Comment: Yes, then also i am getting a same issue, https://..../final_path gives 405 error

Comment: sorry,l my bad. Didn't realize it, please ignore the last comment:

when the call changes to without slash, https://..../final_path/ gives 405 error

Answer (score 6):

Try using `APIRouter` to define the route instead of directly using the `app`. The `APIRouter` has `redirect_slashes` set to `True` by default.

Comment: About time I decluttered my `main.py`. It wasn't easy but was worth it. https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/bigger-applications/ gives me the file hierarchy and a simple example I could plumb in as my first `APIRouter` to prove your answer correct.